# Dynamic CRM 2013 Plugin pipeline stage and database rollback

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have 2 plugins registered on the same pipeline stage (post operation) and triggers on the same entity **Entity A** (create event).

When plugin 1 triggers on **Entity A** (create event) and make changes to **Entity B** and another plugin 2 triggers on **Entity A** (create event) and while making changes to  **Entity A** an exception was thrown.

Does the changes that plugin 1 made on **Entity B** get rolled back since both plugins triggers on the same entity and they have the same pipeline stage OR the changes plugin 1 made to **Entity B** remain and will not be rolled back?

Comment: Essentially you are asking the same thing as in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409277/dynamic-crm-2013-plugin-event-execution-pipeline-and-the-2-minutes-time-out

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually here I am asking about the database roll back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the plugin transaction.

[Event execution pipeline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg327941.aspx)

> Plug-ins may or may not execute within the database transaction of the
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM platform. Whether a plug-in is part of the
>   transaction is dependent on how the message request is processed by
>   the pipeline. You can check if the plug-in is executing in-transaction
>   by reading the IsInTransaction property inherited by
>   IPluginExecutionContext that is passed to the plug-in. **If a plug-in is
>   executing in the database transaction and allows an exception to be
>   passed back to the platform, the entire transaction will be rolled
>   back. Stages (pre-operation) 20 and (post-operation) 40 are guaranteed to be part of the database**
>   transaction while stage 10 may be part of the transaction.
>
> Any registered plug-in that executes during the database transaction
>   and that passes an exception back to the platform cancels the core
>   operation. This results in a rollback of the core operation. In
>   addition, any pre-event or post event registered plug-ins that have
>   not yet executed and any workflow that is triggered by the same event
>   that the plug-in was registered for will not execute.

In your case if the plugins are chained together, and the second one is synchronous the exception from plugin 2 will bubble up to plugin 1. If both plugins are inside a transaction the actions from both plugins are rolled back.

Comment: Do you mean by chained together that both are synchronous and both on the same pipeline stage? What would happens if one or both of them are asynchronous please?

Comment: Chained together is that the first one triggers the second. If the second was asynchronous, then the exception from the second would not be returned to the first. The first is likely to end before the second properly begins. So the first would not roll back due to the transaction, but the second would.